# How to make QML ShaderEffect work on Drawers and Popups

Tags: qt, qml, shader, fragment-shader

I have a ShaderEffect that's always enabled. I have a drawer that can be opened by clicking a button on the top right. I want the shader to be on top of everything that's on the screen, however I notice the the "Hello" text and the drawer don't have the shader applied to them. How can I make sure the shader is applied on everything?

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    width: 1024
    height: 600
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "gray"
        layer.enabled: true

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: qsTr("Hello")
            font.pixelSize: 40
            color: "blue"
        }
    }

    Drawer {
        id: drawer
        width: 0.66 * rect.width
        height: rect.height

        Label {
            text: "Content goes here!"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: drawerButton
        text: "Open drawer"
        anchors.right: parent.right
        onClicked: {
            drawer.open();
        }
    }

    Loader {
        id: effectLoader
        sourceComponent: shaderComponent
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Component {
        id: shaderComponent

        ShaderEffect {
            id: shader
            property variant source: rect
            fragmentShader: "
                varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
                uniform sampler2D source;
                uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
                void main() {
                    gl_FragColor = texture2D(source, qt_TexCoord0) * vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.0, 0.1) * qt_Opacity;
                }"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of the modal overlay? Because [there](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-overlay.html#modal-attached-prop) is a simpler way to achieve that.

Comment: @iam_peter my actual shader is more complicated and changes color often. I want the shader to overlay on top of everything, but as shown in the example, somehow it doesn't apply to popups and drawers. I don't want to use a separate color property on every popup I create, is there a way to have the shader overlay everything?

Comment: The Loader anchors.fill and the ShaderEffect source should all be pointing to the same thing. If you want it applied to your drawer, then, they should all be set in the drawer. If you're applying it to your app, I suspect the Drawer will sit ontop of the ShaderEffect not under it, hence, that is probably why it is not behaving the way you're expecting. As to your actual shader, I'm not sure what it is achieving that couldn't already be achieved with existing components.